# Extract SQL table dependencies with Scala Parsing Combinator

Tags: regex, scala, recursion, sqldependency, parser-combinators

I would like to develop an app to extract table dependencies from SQL statement, specifically the tables referred in SQL FROM clause and Join clause.

For example, SQL SELECT stmt is like below:

```
SELECT .... FROM <Table name> JOIN <list of tables and join condition> WHERE... GROUP BY ... ORDER BY... LIMIT ....
```

So, the tables mentioned in both FROM and JOIN clause are of interest. However, it becomes more complicated if we consider that SQL supports subquery. For example:

```
SELECT .... FROM <Table name> JOIN <list of tables and join condition> WHERE a > (SELECT count(c) FROM ... )
```

Since i am only interested with the dependent tables, i would prefer NOT to implement full SQL lexical parser with Scala Parsing Combinator. But only focus on FROM and Join clause. So, is there a way that i can parse the original SQL stmt with subqueries and generate a flat list of SELECT stmt including both top level SELECT stmt and SELECT stmt in subqueries, in each SELECT stmt, things like column list, WhERE clause, GROUP by clause, etc can all be skipped, but only leave the basic structure and FROM, JOIN clause? For example:

```
SELECT .... FROM <Table name> JOIN <list of tables and join condition> ...
```

Btw, in SQL, FROM keyword can also be used in some SQL functions, for example:

```
insert into AbbrNames(AbbrName) select substring(LongName from 1 for 3) from LongNames
```

and

```
SELECT EXTRACT(month FROM order_date) "Month", COUNT(order_date) "No. of Orders" FROM orders GROUP BY EXTRACT(month FROM order_date) ORDER BY "No. of Orders" DESC;
```